# Sign an apk with signature of another signed apk using apksigner

Tags: android, apk, android-signing, apksigner

I have an unsigned apk `A.apk` and an signed apk `B.apk`

Using `apksigner` tool is it possible to sign `A.apk` with same signature of `B.apk`.

What are the exact commands to do this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

An asymmetric code signature like apksigner creates always requires the private key. But in APKs you will find only the public key and the certificate.

Therefore signing `A.APK` with the same signature as used on `B.APK` is not possible as long as you don't have access to the private key that belongs to the certificate and public key of the signature of `B.APK`.

The only part of the signature of `B.APK` that you could clone would the values shown contained in the certificate (except for the public key, the certificate signature and the certificate fingerprint). But that would fool only a human who does not compare the fingerprint, Android uses the public key and thus directly recognizes that the signature is different. This means such a cloned certificate would be useless.